# Cold calling blur() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a line

```
document.getElementById("firstName").addEventListener("blur", validateField);
```

and :

```
validateField = (event) =>
{
    const el = event.target;
}
```

Now I want to call the validateField() function with the respective element in the `form.addEventListener('submit', function(event)` line.

```
document.getElementById("firstName").blur(); // This is not getting called.
```

But cold-calling blur() isn't working.

What I am trying to do is to populate the bootstrap is-invalid message when the form is called and still invalid.

```
el.classList.add('is-invalid');
el.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "This field is required";
```

Trying to avoid jQuery as I may switch this over to bootstrap version 5.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. From your description, it should work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/w69fnmL0/ Either the form is submitted through a click and the blur event fires before the submit one, either it's submitted "implicitly" (e.g from pressing Enter in the input) in which case the call to `.blur()` will make the *blur* event fire synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think technically, submitting form unfocuses, unless the user presses the enter key to submit. An alternate approach is maybe, you can try to focus on something else than blurring a particular thing!

The following code works for me.

```js
document.getElementById("frm").addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("firstName").blur();
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="frm">
  <input type="text" id="firstName" />
  <input type="submit" value="Press Enter" />
</form>
```

But for the alternate solution:

```js
document.getElementById("frm").addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("frm").focus();
});
```

```css
#frm:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="frm" tabindex="0">
  <input type="text" id="firstName" />
  <input type="submit" value="Press Enter" />
</form>
```